# Алгоритм вычисления функции F(n)

Tags: python, рекурсия

На первый взгляд задача легка и выглядит она вот так:
Алгоритм вычисления функции F(n), где n – целое неотрицательное число, задан
следующими соотношениями:

---

```
F(n) = n + 3, при n ≤ 3  
F(n) = F(n – 2) + n, при n > 3 и четном значении F(n-1),  
F(n) = F(n – 2) + 2· n, при n > 3 и нечетном значении F(n-1)
```

---

Определите сумму значений, являющихся результатом вызова функции для значений n в диапазоне [40; 50].

Мой код:

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n + 3
    elif n > 3 and (f(n-1)) % 2 == 0:
        return f(n-2) + n
    elif n > 3 and (f(n-1)) % 2 != 0:
        return f(n-2) + 2*n
k = 0
for n in range(40, 50+1):
    k += f(n)
print(k)
```

Но идет зацикливание уже на первом элементе. Моя проблема: не могу понять - это условие неправильное или это в коде ошибка?

Comment: Думаю что надо просто кэшировать результаты вычисления. Иначе вы вычисляете одно и тоже десятки тысяч раз.

Comment: 1) Ошибка - Ваша функция не знает, что вернуть, если аргумент равен 3. 2) Поскольку условия взаимоисключающие, три отдельных IF бессмысленны, ELSEIF куда как правильнее.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, я проверял, что вычисляется одно и то же по сто раз подряд. Я и не могу понять, как от этого избавиться.

Comment: @Akina, я исправил код (ошибся когда переписывал). Но elif не вариант: все так же крутиться на месте

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/335866/

Comment: @Alex, ваша программа не знает когда надо остановиться. Вы должны прописать условие(начала и конца) в самой функции, а не делать проход по списку от 40 до 50

Comment: Сто раз подряд это оптимистично. Для n=30 функция вызывается 90 миллионов раз, для 32 уже 340 миллионов, дальше я устал ждать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проще всего использовать для кеширования декоратор `lru_cache`, чтобы не вычислять функцию много раз с одним параметром, а ведь при рекурсии вычисления усложняются в геометрической прогрессии. Кроме того, не нужно проверять обратные условия, они естественно выполняются, если не выполнено прямое условие. Да и вообще тут можно `else` не писать, поскольку при выполнении условий идёт `return` и управление уходит из функции. Ну и само суммирование можно написать короче:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n + 3

    if f(n-1) % 2 == 0:
        return f(n-2) + n

    return f(n-2) + 2*n

k = sum(map(f, range(40, 50+1)))
print(k)
```

Comment: Этот ответ для меня лучше, так как смогу им воспользоваться на ЕГЭ. Спасибо, @CrazyElf!

Comment: @Alex А `lru_cache` вам разрешено пользоваться? )  На самом деле свой кэш написать не сложно, можно использовать простой словарь для этого.

Comment: Да, @CrazyElf, его же не нужно отдельно подключать.

Comment: @Alex Ну, это функция из стандартной библиотеки `functools`, но импорт ведь всё же нужно объявлять. А если в том смысле, что не нужно ставить доп. библиотек, то да, эта библиотека и эта функция входят в любой дистрибутив питона и её полезно знать.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import functools

def cache(func):
    """Кэш предыдущих вызовов функций"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cache_key = args + tuple(kwargs.items())
        if cache_key not in wrapper.cache:
            wrapper.cache[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper.cache[cache_key]
    wrapper.cache = dict()
    return wrapper

@cache
def f(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n + 3
    elif f(n-1) % 2 == 0:
        return f(n-2) + n
    elif f(n-1) % 2 != 0:
        return f(n-2) + 2*n

k = 0
for n in range(40, 50+1):
    k += f(n)

print(k) # 8508
```

Comment: Денис, зачем вы свой lru_cache написали?)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Чтобы человеку наглядно было видно, как это реализовано в коде, а не из под коробки.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, @Denis! И спасибо за то, что расписали, чтобы было наглядно видно)

Answer (score 2):

Необходимости в дополнительных модулях и прочих наворотах нет, должны были изучать расчёт чисел Фибоначчи со складыванием посчитанного в массив/список, здесь всё похоже.

```
def calc(lo, hi):
    f = [3,4,5,6] + [0]*(hi-3)
    for i in range(4, hi+1):
        f[i] = f[i-2] + i + i*(f[i-1]&1) #учёт нечётности - младший бит единица
    return sum(f[lo:hi+1])

print(calc(40, 50))
```

Comment: Так и знал, что можно ещё проще сделать ))